# Chern classes of a ruled surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, characteristic-classes

I am reading Petitjean's thesis (1995). I have trouble making sense of the following:

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a vector bundle (locally free sheaf) of rank $2$ over a curve $C$ with genus $g$ and let $Z = P(\mathcal{E})$. The ruled surface $R$ is defined by the image $R=\rho(Z)$ by some map $\rho:Z\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^3$ that is birational and maps the fibers of $Z$ onto lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Let $\mu_0$ be the degree of $R$, $\pi:Z\rightarrow C$ the projective morphism (bundle map) of $Z$ and for $x\in C$ let $F = \pi^{-1}(x)$. Let $f$ be the class of $F$ in $A^1(Z)$. Then $f^2 = [\pi^{-1}(x)]^2 = \pi^*[x]^2 = 0$ and
$$ \pi^*c_1(\mathcal{E}) = -\mu_0 f\\
\pi^*c_1(T_C) = (2-2g) f.$$

I can't make sense of these equations. $(2-2g)$ is the Euler characteristic and $c_1(T_C)$ is the Euler class of $C$, so I see that there is a connection. But I don't know how to compute the action of $\pi^*$.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: It's enough to notice that $f$ is the pullback of the class of a point.

Comment: Yes, that is by definition. But I don't see how that leads to the relations

Comment: $c_1(T_C) = (2 - 2g)p$, where $p$ is the class of a point.

Comment: Now I feel stupid, that is pretty obvious from the fact that $c_1(T_C)$ is the Euler class of $C$. Now $c_1(\mathcal{E}) = sth.\cdot pt$. Why is this $sth.$ the negative degree of the ruled surface?

Comment: This is the consequence of the Grothendieck's projective bundle formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_bundle#Cohomology_ring_and_Chow_group

Comment: Writing $t = c_1(\mathcal{O}_{Z}(1))$ the formula here is $t^2 + t\cdot \pi^*c_1(\mathcal{E}) = 0$. Letting $\pi^*c_1(\mathcal{E}) = \lambda\cdot f$ we have $t^2 + \lambda t\cdot f = 0$. I guess that $t$ can be thought of as the pull-back of a plane, so $t^2$ is the intersection of the ruled surface with a line, which is $\mu_0$. $\int t\cdot f = 1$ as a plane and a line intersect in a point.
Like this?

Comment: Yes, that's right.